# Using custom User admin breaks change password form in Django's admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm using a custom User admin by:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = User
    ...
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

but when I try to change the password via the admin page I get a 404.

```
user object with primary key u'4/password' does not exist.
```

Reverting back to the default User admin works fine.

Answer (score 19):

The default `UserAdmin` in [`django.contrib.auth.admin`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/admin.py) implements a lot of functionality, including the change password page.

Your `CustomUserAdmin` should subclass `UserAdmin` instead of `admin.ModelAdmin`, unless you want to reimplement that functionality yourself.

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    # as an example, this custom user admin orders users by email address
    ordering = ('email',)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Comment: This worked for me but the having the this code: exclude = ('is_superuser', 'user_permissions') breaks it.

Comment: @wenbert you need to override `fieldsets`. Both is_superuser and user_permissions are included in `UserAdmin.fieldsets`. You cannot include a field in fieldsets then exclude it.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Also:

As per [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-django-contrib-admin), if you inherit from AbstractBaseUser you cannot use the default UserAdmin; or, put another way, you can but only a subset of the functionality will work - changing an existing password might work, but adding a new user will throw exceptions.