# How to get 'change password' functionality with Custom User Model in Django 1.5

Tags: django, django-admin

In a Django 1.5 project, I've created a custom User model extending from AbstractBaseUser to make the email address the primary key (instead of a username).

How do I get the change password functionality for UserAdmin in the django admin interface? I tried extending UserAdmin with a class called CustomUserAdmin (much like the answer suggested in [Using custom User admin breaks change password form in Django's admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109647/using-custom-user-admin-breaks-change-password-form-in-djangos-admin)), but I get the following error message

```
CustomUserAdmin.list_display[0], 'username' is not a callable or an attribute of 'CustomUserAdmin' or found in the model 'User'.
```

I basically want the default admin interface *except* the password field (which I want from UserAdmin).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your custom User model doesn't have 'username' field. And since CustomUserAdmin is extending UserAdmin, which assumes 'username' field is present; we are getting this error.

I would suggest you add a 'username' field in your custom model and store the same value of 'email' field in it.

Or override all the attributes of UserAdmin class which uses 'username'. 
Eg:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ['email', 'first_name'.....]
```

Comment: i would rather not have a hacky solution that has to (1) get rid of the username assumption in UserAdmin or (2) fake a username field. A big reason why I went through the trouble of extending AbstractBaseUser over BaseUser was because I didn't want to deal with an extraneous username field

Comment: @fangsterr UserAdmin class is based on django auth User model. Now we have a custom User model, which is quite different from auth User; but we want CustomUserAdmin to subclass UserAdmin. The only way to achieve this is to override the attributes/functions of UserAdmin to suit our structure. If you don't want to do this, then CustomUserAdmin should reimplement that functionality.